# Jquery Syntax Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

What I want to do is:

`#p12-1` should fade in and out (its a click here button).

When clicked, it should look at what value the variable `$section` is and then choose which section to run. When running the section it should also increment the variable `$section`. This should then mean that each section will show the next divs and hide some/all of the old ones each time `#p12-1` is clicked.

```
if (index == 11) {
    $section == (parseInt(1));
    $("#prev").show();
    $("#next").show();
    $("#p12-1").delay(1000).fadeIn("slow", function() {
            (function loop() {
                $("#p12-1").delay(200).fadeTo("slow", 0.5, function ()  {
                    $("#p12-1").delay(200).fadeTo("slow", 1, loop);
                });
            }());
    });
$("p12-1").click(function ()    {
    if ($section == 1)  {
        var $section = (parseInt(currentValue) + 1);        
            $("#p12-2").fadeOut(1000);
            $("#p12-3").fadeOut(1000);          
            $("#p12-4").fadeIn(1000);
            $("#p12-5").fadeIn(1000);
    };
    if ($section == 2)  {
        var $section = (parseInt(currentValue) + 1);
            $("#p12-4").fadeOut(1000);
            $("#p12-5").fadeOut(1000);
            $("#p12-6").fadeIn(1000);
            $("#p12-7").fadeIn(1000);
            $("#p12-8").fadeIn(1000);
    };
    if ($section == 3)  {
        var $section = (parseInt(currentValue) + 1);
            $("#p12-6").fadeOut(1000);
            $("#p12-9").fadeIn(1000);
            $("#p12-10").fadeIn(1000);
    };
    if ($section == 4)  {
        var $section = (parseInt(currentValue) + 1);
            $("#p12-6").fadeOut(1000);
            $("#p12-9").fadeOut(1000);
            $("#p12-10").fadeOut(1000);
            $("#p12-11").fadeIn(1000);
            $("#p12-12").fadeIn(1000);          
    };
});
}
```

The HTML:

```
<div class="main-slide main-slide-12" style="display:none;">
    <div id="p12-1" style="display:none;"><img src="images/p12-1.png" /></div>
    <div style="display:block;" id="p12-2"><img src="images/p12-2.png" /></div>
    <div style="display:block;" id="p12-3"><img src="images/p12-3.png" /></div>
    <div style="display:none;" id="p12-4"><img src="images/p12-4.png" /></div>
    <div style="display:none;" id="p12-5"><img src="images/p12-5.png" /></div>
    <div style="display:none;" id="p12-6"><img src="images/p12-6.png" /></div>
    <div style="display:none;" id="p12-7"><img src="images/p12-7.png" /></div>
    <div style="display:none;" id="p12-8"><img src="images/p12-8.png" /></div>
    <div style="display:none;" id="p12-9"><img src="images/p12-9.png" /></div>
    <div style="display:none;" id="p12-10"><img src="images/p12-10.png" /></div>
    <div style="display:none;" id="p12-11"><img src="images/p12-11.png" /></div>
    <div style="display:none;" id="p12-12"><img src="images/p12-12.png" /></div>
</div>
```

Unfortunately, all these items are needed and a few need to be displayed and hidden at different time. I believe the problem is with the syntax, as I will be able to edit the option in each of the `if ($section == X)` blocks.

Comment: please show your markup, I guess this can be done much easier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand some of your code, but here is an idea you might like.  Instead of controlling what an element does in the code, you can use a simple inversion of control -- since elements can have multiple classes you can have the element state when it is shown and hidden.  This makes for simpler (and I believe clearer) code.

Thus the HTML might look like this:

```
<div class="main-slide main-slide-12" style="display:none;">
    <div id="p12-1" style="display:none;"><img src="images/p12-1.png" /></div>
    <div class="hide-1"                      ><img src="images/p12-2.png" /></div>
    <div class="hide-1"                      ><img src="images/p12-3.png" /></div>
    <div class="show-1 hide-2"               ><img src="images/p12-4.png" /></div>
    <div class="show-1 hide-2"               ><img src="images/p12-5.png" /></div>
    <div class="       show-2 hide-3 hide-4" ><img src="images/p12-6.png" /></div>
    <div class="       show-2"               ><img src="images/p12-7.png" /></div>
    <div class="       show-2"               ><img src="images/p12-8.png" /></div>
    <div class="              show-3 hide-4" ><img src="images/p12-9.png" /></div>
    <div class="              show-3 hide-4" ><img src="images/p12-10.png" /></div>
    <div class="                     show-4" ><img src="images/p12-11.png" /></div>
    <div class="                     show-4" ><img src="images/p12-12.png" /></div>
</div>
```

Then your javascript will look something like this:

```
$("#p12-1").click(function ()    {
    $(".hide-"+$section).fadeOut(1000);
    $(".show-"+$section).fadeIn(1000);
});
```

This seems to me to reveal potential bugs when looking at the html (eg p12-11 is never hidden).

Answer (score 0):

```
if (index == 11) {
$section == (parseInt(1));
$("#prev").show();
$("#next").show();
$("#p12-1").delay(1000).fadeIn("slow", function() {
    (function loop() {
        $("#p12-1").delay(200).fadeTo("slow", 0.5, function ()  {
            $("#p12-1").delay(200).fadeTo("slow", 1, loop);
        });
    }());
});
$("######p12-1").click(function ()    {
```

try adding the '#' character... jquery cant find the element p12-1 because it doesn't exists and will not fire the click event

Comment: I'm guessing you added the extra 5 `#` characters for emphasis not suggesting this is correct syntax for a jQuery selector.